# I am not able to identify elements using protractor in angular 2 application

Tags: angular, protractor

Here is my html for angular 2 applications. I am executing my tests in chrome

```html
<md-card-title _ngcontent-c10="" class="ra-card-title mat-card-title">
  <a _ngcontent-c10="">Massachusetts Division of Banks Issues Decision Establishing Limit on Maximum Allowable Fee for Dishonored Checks for State - Chartered Financial Institutions</a>
</md-card-title>
<div _ngcontent-c10="" class="ra-card-header__footer">
  <md-card-subtitle _ngcontent-c10="" class="ra-card-code mat-card-subtitle">BLN3594</md-card-subtitle>

  <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="ra-card-menu">
    <span _ngcontent-c10="" aria-haspopup="true" class="ra-card-menu-button">...</span>
    <md-menu _ngcontent-c10="" role="menu" xposition="before" yposition="below">
      <!---->
    </md-menu>
  </div>
</div>

<md-card-subtitle _ngcontent-c10="" class="ra-card-code mat-card-subtitle">BLN3594</md-card-subtitle>
```

I am not able to click on the menu button using

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@class='ra-card-menu-button'])[0]")).click();
```

But if I use below javascript executor , it is working fine.

```js
var scrpt = "return document.getElementsByClassName('ra-card-menu-button')[0].click();";
browser.executeScript(scrpt).then(function(text) {
  logger.log('info', 'Script is: ' + scrpt);

});
```

protractor version is  5.1.1.

Could anyone please help me to identify the issue

Comment: Seems some issue with when I copied the html. Here is updated one  <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="ra-card-menu">
    <span _ngcontent-c10="" aria-haspopup="true" class="ra-card-menu-button">...</span>
    <md-menu _ngcontent-c10="" role="menu" xposition="before" yposition="below"><!----> </md-menu>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Which ChromeDriver version are you using? Can you also post an example of your script?

Comment: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this (without extra right parenthesis, and the number points to the first element):

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@class='ra-card-menu-button'][1]")).click();
```

Comment: Getting error like this when I tried the above   - Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[@class='ra-card-men
u-button'][1])

Answer (score 0):

What should work is this `element(by.css('.ra-card-menu-button')).click();`

Mind the `.` to identify the `class`. You can even use the *shorthand* notation of protractor, that would make the code look like this `$(.ra-card-menu-button').click();`, see also [this](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$) and [this](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using the webdriver command

Yet to identify why my page says it is not angular page though it is deveoped in angular 2