# Cucumber Protractor times out after using then() on elements selected using Protractors element function

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, chai, cucumberjs

I have an issue which description matches perfectly with [I am not able to identify elements using protractor in angular 2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016099/i-am-not-able-to-identify-elements-using-protractor-in-angular-2-application) but for me the problem is not fixed by adding # before the id value

Here is the code below:

```
When('I select my input box', (callback) => {

  let inputbox = element(by.css('#roomWidthInput'));
  console.log('inputBox promise set');

  var scrpt = "return document.getElementById('roomWidthInput');";
  browser.executeScript(scrpt).then(function (text) {
    console.log('info', 'Script is: ' + scrpt);
  });

  inputbox.isPresent().then(function(isElementVisible) {
    console.log('hello!');
    expect(isElementVisible).to.be.true;
    callback();
  });
});
```

The console logs:

- inputBox promise set
- info Script is: return document.getElementById('roomWidthInput');

and then it throws Error: function timed out after 5000 milliseconds.

I have also tried using `by.id` locator with exactly the same results.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please tell us which version of Cucumber you used?

Comment: "cucumber": "^2.3.1", "protractor": "^5.1.2", "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.2.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has no matter with `protractor can't find element`, It's due to your step definition function execution time duration exceeded the default timeout:  5 secs.

You should change the default timeout as below:

**Cucumber 3 and above**

```
// supports/timeout.js
var { setDefaultTimeout } = require("cucumber");
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
```

**Cucumber 2 above, but lower than Cucumber 3**

```
// supports/timeout.js
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function({setDefaultTimeout}) {
  setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
});
```

**Cucumber 1 and lower**

```
// supports/timeout.js
module.exports = function() {
    this.setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
};
```

In protractor `conf.js`, add the timeout.js into cucumberOpts.require:

```
// set allScriptsTimeout to fix asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds
allScriptsTimeout: 600 * 1000, 

cucumberOpts: {     
   require: [
      "supports/timeout.js",
   ]
},

onPrepare: function() {
   // add this when page opened by browser.get() is not angular page
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
}
```

Comment: I did that, but then I got exactly the same results, but this time with a different error: E/launcher - Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular applicati
on.

Comment: add `allScriptsTimeout` to fix the `11 seconds timeout`, more information can find from http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Comment: I am debugging a pure angular application and I am only navigating within it (using browser.get to do it), but for some reason `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` did the trick! Now my input box is found using exactly the same code and I am able to clear and send keys to it which proves that your solution worked. Many thanks, I have spent weeks on this, you have definitely earned an accepted answer :)